# create components dynamically

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, adobe

I have requirement in AdvancedDataGrid.

In Advanced Data Datagrid with columns checkbox,textfield, textarea,button,radiobutton. and ADD Button and SUBMIT Button. When i click on ADD Button, those above all fields are need to add dynamically in next row.If i click 10 times on ADD Button, 10 rows with all above fileds need to be added.

If Have any sample code please forward to my gmail id:rkcy000@gmail.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should work with the underlying data provider for the adding of new rows. whenever the add button is pressed do

```
adg.dataProvider.addItem( newItemFromAboveRow );
```

and the ADG will sort out the display for you.

Answer (score 0):

Create custom item/row renderers. More [Using Item Renderers and Item Editors](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=cellrenderer_1.html)